# TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined returned JSON issue using Realtime Firebase in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to populate the 'results' array with JSON data from Realtime Firebase Database but I get

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'results' of undefined

Here is the VueJs code.

```
    <template>
        <div id="show-results">
            <h1>Data</h1>
                 <input type="text" v-model="search"  placeholder="search results" />
                <div v-for="result in results" class="single-result">
                <h2>{{ result.Speed }}</h2>
                <article>{{ result.DiscManufacturer }}</article>
            </div>

        </div>
    </template>

    <script>

    import db from '@/firebase/init'
    import firebase from 'firebase'

    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                results: [
                ],
               search: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {

        },  created() {  
firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => { snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => { this.results = JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.val());

console.log(this.results);
 });
}
    </script>
```

Please help. I am a beginner in VueJS.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes with the use of `function() { }` instead of arrow function in the `.forEach()` method: you are losing the reference to `this` (i.e. it becomes non-lexical). This means that the `this` in your callback no longer refers to the VueJS component itself, but to the `Window` object instead.

Therefore, changing the callback in your `.forEach()` method to use the arrow function should fix the error you're encountering:

```
snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
    this.results = childSnapshot.val();   
});
```

Pro-tip: since your callback contains a single line, you can make it even more readable by not using curly brackets:

```
snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => this.results = childSnapshot.val());
```

Comment: Nice and quick explanation. One question I have is why would `this` be `undefined` if it references the `Window` object? I would have thought that in this case `this` would be defined but it just would not have the property `results`.

Comment: It says "ReferenceError: snapshot is not defined" now. Please help. I would request you to rewrite the full function for created(){  //Everything inside } so that I can test and not do any stupid mistake.

Comment: @harshit `firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
   snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
     this.results = childSnapshot.val();   
    });
});`

Comment: That error is gone but in place of output, it is just printing empty CSS boxes. Nothing in it. Not printing the values from database I am expecting to print.

Comment: One console.log(this.results) I get all results though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this` is not your Vue instance.

Try binding `this` to your `forEach`.

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
  this.results = childSnapshot.val();   
}.bind(this));
```